# Angular Google Map embed fix The Hide Location Marker When Zooming

Tags: angular, google-maps, embed

i used this code for show location with google map embed and worked correctly

```
 'https://maps.google.com/maps?q=' + this.lat + ',' + this.lng + '&hl=fa&z=12&amp&output=embed'
```

[image]

i use 12 for zoom and show marker but when zoom with ctrl+mouse scroll  hide marker

[image]

[image]

i use iframe on html to show map

```
<iframe *ngIf="lat>0" width="100%" height="800" id="gmap_canvas"
              [src]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(getAddress())" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes"
              marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">
            </iframe>
```

Comment: Does your marker moved out of view-port or it is been removed from map?
If it is move out of view-port with zoom then you can bind an event listener to map zoom event and re-centered the map with marker position.

Comment: Thanks for answer. the location marker hides.According to the gif photo I now added .when scroll hide the location